# Displaying Sqlite3 results in a HTML table with python

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlite

I am using a SQLite3 db file to retrieve data and store it in a variable so that I can use it to display the results on a HTML table.

This is how I am storing the results from the query:

```
test = c.execute("SELECT column_name from table_name LIMIT 11")
```

However, when I try to display it in the table, using  `"{%for x in test%}"`, the output is being displayed like this: `(1.234,)`. What do I need to change for the output to look like this: `1.234` so without the bracket and comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a list of all results of your query, you should use [`fetchall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall), which, according to the docs:

> Fetches all (remaining) rows of a query result, returning a list. Note
>   that the cursor’s arraysize attribute can affect the performance of
>   this operation. An empty list is returned when no rows are available.

Try this:

```
c = sqlite3.connect('db_path.db')
cur = c.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT column_name from table_name LIMIT 11")
test = cur.fetchall()
```

Your html would then look like this:

```
<table>
  {% for row in test %}
  <tr>
    <th> {{ row[0] }}</th>
  </tr> 
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: "TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable" I have tried this before

Comment: Okay I tried this and get this error "AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchone'" Also I am doing this "test = c.execute("SELECT column_name from table_name LIMIT 11)"

Comment: You should be doing this with a cursor. I thought `c` was a cursor, and not a connection. You should do `cur = c.cursor()`, then   `cur.execute("select ....")` then `test = cur.fetchone()[0]`

Comment: Okay so this did something. Before my output was a list which filled the table in the output and since I was using a for loop to iterate through each item and output it in the table "{%for x in amsterdam%}" now it will not let me do that because its not a list anymore.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. If you want a list, you should use fetchall() - I updated the answer with it.

Comment: Did you test the code in updated answer? Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I tried the code and it does the same thing as before, it doesn't get rid of the (,) "bracket and comma" in the output.

Comment: Can you print in the console log to see if it is returning the correct output? Also, could you post the html?

Comment: In your html, inside the `{%for x in test%}`, when you want to use the retrieved value,  you should be using `{{ x[0] }}`, since fetchall returns a list of rows.

Comment: How is `{%for x in test%}` being interpreted in HTML? Is it using some kind of template library? If so, which one, and how to include it?