# Django sqlite3 database displayed on HTML table

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter (by column element) and display information from a sqlite3 database directly onto a HTML table. I've read in multiple places that you should use Django's ORM instead of a database. However, the data is continuously updating in the database so I'm not sure if this is a route to pursue with this. TL;DR I'm looking for a way to open a sqlite3 .db file and chuck it into an HTML table.

I have looked over the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/) regarding models, as well as looked at several different websites/tutorials ([here](https://djangobook.com/mdj2-models/), [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34813278/displaying-sqlite3-results-in-a-html-table-with-python); I even found [django-tables2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which I thought was going to work), all to no avail. I'm essentially at a roadblock and I'm not sure where to go and/or what to do.

Here is how the database is structured:

```
---------------------------------------------
| Name | Type | Col 1 | ... | Col N | Color |
---------------------------------------------
| Gary | A    | Data  | ... | Data! | Green |
| Mark | A    | Data  | ... | Data? | Blue  |
| Ray  | B    | Data  | ... | Data. | Red   |
...
```

As far as the HTML is concerned, I'd like to use for loop similar to this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        ...
        <th>Col N</th>
    </tr>
        {% for row in data %}
    <tr> 
        <td>{{ row }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

One thing to note as well is that the last column in the above sample database is not being shown on the table.

Comment: Do you need to use Django? [datasette](https://datasette.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) might be more suited for this.

Comment: You also don't _need_ to use the Django ORM, you can still import `sqlite3` and use [`dataTables`](https://datatables.net/) to show the data. It's a bit hard to know what you need here